# UIDocumentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated navigation bar style is incorrect for ios15

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios15, uidocumentinteraction

I use the UIDocumentInteractionController to present an image full screen and since upgrading to xcode 13, iOS 15 devices have white and translucent navigation bars when doing `[_documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];`. All other navigation bars are fine.

This is what the delegate looks like

```
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    UINavigationController* navController = [self navigationController];
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor primaryColor];
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor primaryColor];
    navController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor primaryColor];

    return navController;
}
```

The closest I came to fixing the issue was doing this in the delegate

```
    UINavigationBarAppearance *app = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    [app configureWithOpaqueBackground];
    app.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlack];

    navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = app;
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

however the bar stays translucent. This is the result, the colour should be red.
[image: Navigation bar is translucent]
Setting `navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` doesnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, now that its at least readable I'm leaving it for now until someone hopefully gives a solution. Just upvote the question to give it more traction if you need help also